# Regular expression to detect string contains only . or ? or?

Tags: java, regular-language

I would like to match string which contains only . or only ? or only !. The string can contains many chars e.g "..." or "????".

I can create expression for one mark ^(!+)$ but how to add or condition? Something like this: ^(!+)$|^(?+)$|^(.\+)$ doesn't work.

Comment: Which language? Java, right? Just want to be sure.

Comment: Right, java. I am new with regular expression.

Comment: If you need to learn regexp, here is an *excellent* book on the topic: http://freecomputerbooks.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 2):

This works: `^(\.+|\!+|\?+)$`

I work these from the inside out. In this case, I started with this:
`.` - but that's special
so, remove that special meaning:
`\.`
Now, say I would be happy with more than one:
`\.+`
Now, say only that in a string:
`^\.+$`
Now, add the first alternative:
`^\.+|\!+$`
then do the final one

Here's the tool I used to test this:

https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydy85zar

Comment: I think you need a group to make the alternation work properly. i.e. more like this: `^(\.+|\!+|\?+)$`. (Or use `matches()` rather than `find()` with ^ and $). Check the "find()" column in the output on your linked tester for proof.

Comment: I thought saw, too, Rich, but the tester I used didn't have any trouble with it. Probably because it's so simple, just single characters with quantifiers.

Comment: The tester you linked to does show that it is wrong: follow that link, then click "Java", then look at the "find()" column for the "`.?asdf`" counter-example. It says "Yes" when it should say "No". If you are relying on the regex being used only with "match()", then you should drop the "^" and "$" altogether. If you are not, then you need to fix them. HTH